# How to specify thin to use Rack adapter rather than Rails adapter when starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, thin

I am using Capistrano to deploy an app. The following command works if I enter it at the terminal via SSH: 
thin start -p 20480 -e production -d

But when it is ran through Capfile like: 
run "cd #{current_path} && thin start -p 20480 -e production -d"

It has this error in the log:

> > Writing PID to tmp/pids/thin.pid
> >     Using rails adapter
> >     Exiting!
> >     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p369/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load': syntax error on line 2, col 8:`  specs:' (ArgumentError)

The difference is the second lin: **Using rails adapter**. When I enter this command at the terminal by myself, it says **Using Rack adapter.**

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Best regards,
Tony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try stating explicitly whant adapter you want to use. You can do this using the  --adapter switch. So your line of code will look like this:

```
run "cd #{current_path} && thin start -p 20480 -e production -d --adapter rack"
```

Maybe this helps.

---

PS.

thin --help says:

```
-A, --adapter NAME   Rack adapter to use (default: autodetect)
                     (rack, rails, ramaze, halcyon, merb, 
                      mack, mack, file)
```